# override default method route from plugin in nopcommerce in 3.8

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I want to override search controller. When I try to install a plugin, I get an error exception what multiple type were found for the controller named `Catalog`.

> Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Catalog'. This can happen if the route that services this request ('AdvanceSearch') does not specify namespaces to search for a controller that matches the request. If this is the case, register this route by calling an overload of the 'MapRoute' method that takes a 'namespaces' parameter.

And my route priority is most(100).

```
public void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        // Product Search,
        routes.MapRoute("Plugin.Misc.Twigoh.Search",
         "Search",
         new { controller = "Catalog", action = "Search" },
         new[] { "Nop.Plugin.Misc.Twigoh.Search.Controllers" });


    }
    public int Priority
    {
        get
        {
            return 100;
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gzue2qhdtweel13/Screenshot%202016-10-07%2014.57.47.png?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override your route like this:

When you override route, then you should use `MapLocalizedRoute`(*not `MapRoute`*) which is override localized route. Here you are trying to define route which is already define.

Here do not use `MapRoute` use `MapLocalizedRoute` in this way.

```
routes.MapLocalizedRoute("Plugin.Misc.Twigoh.Search",
                            "search/",
                            new { controller = "Catalog", action = "Search" },
                            new[] { "Nop.Plugin.Misc.Twigoh.Search.Controllers" });
```

**Edit:**

> I want same route and functionality but default controller can't have
>   "/" search feature little bit different

`/search` is default route of product search, you can see in `Nop.Web > Infrastructure > RouteProvider.cs`

Hope this helps!

Comment: no i want same route and functionality but default controller can't have "/" search feature little bit different

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gzue2qhdtweel13/Screenshot%202016-10-07%2014.57.47.png?dl=0

Comment: are you using `MapLocalizedRoute`? do not use `MapRoute`

Comment: Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Catalog'. This can happen if the route that services this request ('AdvanceSearch') does not specify namespaces to search for a controller that matches the request. If this is the case, register this route by calling an overload of the 'MapRoute' method that takes a 'namespaces' parameter.

Comment: Yes change mapRoute to MapLocalizedRoute

Comment: And `search/` ?

Comment: May be this because of you have create controller and method with same name as it's in default,  it could be the issue!

Comment: what was the issue?

Comment: Route Defined in querystring

Answer (score 1):

May be you rename your project so that the file name of the assembly changes, it's possible for you to have two versions.

So remove old .dll from bin folder and build your project.

Comment: Clean project and rebuild when debug solution

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gzue2qhdtweel13/Screenshot%202016-10-07%2014.57.47.png?dl=0